# Прокси на .Net, модифицирующий страницы

Tags: c#, .net, http, vb.net

День добрый.
Имеется локальный веб сервер, который реализован внутри программы (исходников нету, ничего не настраивается кроме IP и порта на котором она висит). При обращении на этот порт через браузер появляется html страница, которую надо изменить. Мысль пришла в голову только одна, перехватывать как входящий так и исходящий http трафик, фильтровать его (удалять ненужные данные, добавлять нужные). Собственно как это можно реализовать на .NET?
Например наверное надо принимать запрос на одном порту, работать с трафиком и потом кидать на другой локальный порт http трафик, если кто работал в этом направлении, подскажите где посмотреть пример чего то подобного.
Все это дело под виндой.

Comment: вы хотите написать прокси-сервер, но это слово у вас не прозвучало ни разу в вопросе. http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Articles.aspx?id=66&mode=art как образец

Comment: да слово не прозвучало, но ссылка которую вы дали именно то что надо, огромное спасибо.

Comment: ну как в итоге, получилось? Не хотите дать ответ на собственный вопрос, оставив последующим читателям указание?

Comment: Я бы дал ответ если бы я прямо сейчас над ним работал, больше чем описано в статье на которую вы дали ссылку, описывать нечего. Можно закрыть или удалить вопрос, если он мешает. Или позже я выложу готовый пример, но когда это будет я сказать не могу.